# Issue for connecting two sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm using C# for programming a network application. I'm using a thread to listen an IPEndPoint and answer it.

And another socket to send requests which is using in button handlers. I'm using the TCP protocol.

I've done it many times but today when I was testing it after a long time I understand my application can't connect well.

When I use telnet I can connect to my socket or when I create a test socket I can connect it by my application. There is no strange exception or error and I forward ports by Mono.Nat but problem is not ports because it can communicate with server or client side of itself.

Here is my listening socket code:

```
public static async void HandleIncomingConnection()
{
        await ConfigConnection();
        Socket Incomingsockresponde = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), StandardPorts[0]);
        string NetworkCommandString;
        byte[] BytedNetworkString = new byte[1024];
        byte[] BytedNetworkFile = new byte[1024 * 100000];
        int Len, checker = 0, check = 0;

        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                check++;
                Incomingsockresponde.Bind(LocalEndPoint);
                Incomingsockresponde.Listen(1);
                Incomingsockresponde = Incomingsockresponde.Accept();
                MessageBox.Show("debug:\n Some remote host connected:" + Incomingsockresponde.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Host flagged . . .", "Yeap!");
                var mainp = new mainprivate();
                mainp.Hstate = "Host not flagged";

                try
                {
                    //todo:log stuff
                    Len = Incomingsockresponde.Receive(BytedNetworkString);
                    NetworkCommandString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BytedNetworkString, 0, Len);
                    RespondeCommand(NetworkCommandString, Incomingsockresponde);
                    Incomingsockresponde.Disconnect(true);
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    checker++;
                    MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong with this error:\n" + err.ToString(), "Woops!");

                    if (checker == 3)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Host has some issues for connections", "Woops!");
                        var main2p = new mainprivate();
                        main2p.Hstate = "Host has some issues on connections";
                        return;
                    }   
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong with this error:\n" + err.ToString(), "Woops!");

                if(check == 3)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Host not flagged . . .", "Woops!");
                    var main2p = new mainprivate();
                    main2p.Hstate = "Host not flagged";
                    return;
                }

                if(Incomingsockresponde.Connected == true)
                    Incomingsockresponde.Disconnect(true);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //debug:
        MessageBox.Show("Here we go ports :\n" + "ResPort: " + ResPort + "-- - StreamPort:" + StreamPort + "-- - EmerPort:" + EmerPort);
        Thread HandleIncomingConnectionThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HandleIncomingConnection));
        HandleIncomingConnectionThread.Start();
        connections[0] = "test";
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new welcome());
    }
```

And this is my request code below:

```
try
{
    Program.availsock.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(haddr[0]), Convert.ToInt16(haddr[1]));
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can't reach the host" + valstr);
    //return;
    Program.hostsn--;
    addacchost(myKeys[i], valstr, new Size(944, 217), "Uavailable remote host");
    goto endsock;
}

//connected
byte[] tmpmssg = new byte[1024];
tmpmssg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Program.hey);
Program.availsock.Send(tmpmssg);
int tmplng = Program.availsock.Receive(tmpmssg);
string rcdval = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(tmpmssg, 0, tmplng);
haddr = null;
Program.availsock.Close(0);
haddr = rcdval.Split('%');

if (!Program.supporteddistros.Contains(haddr[0]) || !Program.supportedversions.Contains(haddr[1]) || !Program.supportedtypes.Contains(haddr[2]))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unsupported remote host" + valstr);
    //delete that from there 
    Program.oridndic.RemoveAt(checker - 1);
    Program.hostsn--;
    addacchost(myKeys[i], valstr, new Size(944, 217), "Unsupported remote host");
    //acchost.Loadlbl = "Unsupported/Deleted";
    //hosts2.Controls.Add(acchost);
    //return;
    goto endsock;
}
```

I check ports by `netstat -ab` and it was listening but it just received connections by telnet or my test socket not request side of my code or reverse my request side just sent request to my test socket.

Is this about my code structure?

Am I making a mistake?

**Edit**: I also defined a inbound rule for all ports and other stuff for windows firewall.

I'm so confused I never faced this situation I'm just looking for a clue.

Answer (score -1):

Ok well that was just a wrong convert for port i did :

```cs
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), Convert.toInt16( port int here));
```

and it should be :

```cs
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), int.Parse(Port int here));
```

Thanks peoples dont help :/